# Master theorem: $T(n)=10T(n/9)+n\lg(n)$

Tags: algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, recurrence-relation, master-theorem

I am told to solve the recurrence
$$T(n)=10T(n/9)+n\lg(n)$$
using the Master theorem. I then try to use case 3. However, I am unable to show that for $f(n)=n\lg(n)$ then $10f(n/9) \leq cn\lg(n)$ for $c < 1$ and all sufficiently large $n$. Is it wrong to use case 3? Or does the Master theorem even apply?

Comment: You should state the exat version of the master theorem you are using, there is a raft of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case 3 does not apply. Indeed:
$$
f(n) = n \log n \not\in \Omega(n^{\log_9 10}) = \Omega(n^{\log_b a}).
$$

However case $1$ applies since, for $0<c \le 0.01$
$$
f(n) = n \log n \in O(n^{1.04 - 0.01}) \subset O(n^{\log_9 10 - 0.01} ) \subseteq O(n^{\log_b a - c} ).
$$

This shows that $T(n) \in \Theta(n^{\log_9 10})$.